# Где брать номер версии для указания в зависимостях?

Tags: android-studio

В начале работы с Open Street Map разработчики ([здесь](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/How-to-add-the-osmdroid-library-via-Gradle)) указывают на необходимость вставки зависимостей в файл build.gradle.

```
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(INSERT_VERSION_HERE)'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:(INSERT_VERSION_HERE)'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:(INSERT_VERSION_HERE)'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:(INSERT_VERSION_HERE)'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:(INSERT_VERSION_HERE)'
```

Подскажите где брать значения для подстановки вместо INSERT_VERSION_HERE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У этой библиотеки есть [ссылка](https://github.com/osmdroid/) где указана версия:

```
Current Release: 6.1.5 Dec 14st, 2019

Current Development version: 6.1.6-SNAPSHOT

Next Release Version (planned): 6.1.6
```

P.S. Когда я не могу найти версию, то я просто пишу 1.0.0 и дальше студия предложит изменить версию до самой последней. Не уверен что правильно делаю, но это работает :)

Comment: То есть везде прописать 6.1.5    ?

Comment: да, если не будет нормально подтягиваться, то укажите 1.0.0 и дальше вылезет окошко с предложением изменить версию до самой последней на данный момент.